# How to bypass outlook 2FA when used in PHP and IMAP?

Tags: php, outlook, imap

**Context**

Recently, I have decided to activate 2FA to my outlook email.

However, due to this 2FA implementation, IMAP cannot access the mail server directly and this incur an error in my PHP script.

As of now the code that I have written to access my outlook with IMAP is simply `$mbox = imap_open("{localhost:143}INBOX", "user_id", "password");`

**Question**

Is there any way to bypass this such that when IMAP is reading from the mail server, it does not have to go through any authentication?

Comment: We ran into similar issue with gmail and 2FA a couple month ago. To this day, the only viable solution I could discover was to implement Gmail API and do everything through it.  There is a workaround that's also worth mentioning. It is possible to setup a forwarding rule on inbox that you want to 'read' and send all data into an inbox that does not have 2FA to use IMAP on.

Comment: You want to use 2FA, and at the same time you want to not use it, and you have a conflict. Well, of course. I think you need to clarify the real problem — why do you want to both use and not use 2FA? Meanwhile I'll vote to close.

Comment: If there was any way to bypass this, then the 2FA would be pointless to begin with. Making this IMAP connection from your PHP script, is no different from any other client trying to authenticate against the mail server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, outlook allows the users to create a password for those applications that do not support 2FA. You can find the reference link [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12409/microsoft-account-app-passwords-and-two-step-verification).

However, this means that the site is still not fully secured.